# Error obtained in Amazon lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

We have created a chat bot in Amazon lex. The bot shows the following error when it tries to access the lambda function.

**An error has occurred: Access denied while invoking lambda function.Please check the permissions on the IAM policy used to create the bot**

Can you help us in fixing this error.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that the root of this issue is on the IAM role which is associated with your Lex Bot.  Lex assumes this role when invoking your Lambda function, and needs both 1) a policy that allows the role to invoke Lambda, and 2) a trust policy that allows Amazon Lex to assume that role on your behalf.  From the error message you’re seeing, I would expect that it is the trust policy which may be configured on your Bot’s role.

**1.** In the Permissions tab for the IAM role, choose Inline Policies, and then attach the following custom policy.

```
{ 
    "Version": "2012-10-17", 
    "Statement": [ 
        { 
            "Action": [ 
            "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "polly:SynthesizeSpeech"
            ], 
        "Effect": "Allow", 
        "Resource": "*" 
        } 
     ] 
}
```

**2.** In the Trust Relationships tab, choose Edit Trust Relationship, and specify the Amazon Lex service principal ("lex.amazonaws.com"). The updated policy should look as shown:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lex.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please see item 2 in our Getting Started documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-bp-prep.html ) as a reference

Full disclosure: I work on Amazon Lex as a Product Manager

Comment: the iam role associated with the lexbot is service-linked. when trying to edit it in the console there is a note on top: "This service-linked role cannot be modified in IAM. You can modify this role from the AWS service that depends on this role". Cannot attach inline policy, cannot modify trust and cannot edit the attached policy for the same reason (policy used only for service-linked role).

Comment: when using the console to configure a bot, you will notice that lex is granted permission to trigger the lambda function on a per intent basis, through the lambda function trigger policy (trigger tab in your lambda aws console). Unfortunately you can edit that only using the cli...

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-cli-update-lambda.html

Lex is using the push model to trigger the lambda function, on a per intent function policy basis.

"Use the Lambda AddPermission function to enable the OrderFlowers intent to call the Lambda Invoke operation."

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_AddPermission.html

Unfortunately, resource policies cannot be edited through the aws console.